# Namespace error running a shell command in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, shell, namespaces

I am really stumped on something I need help getting past.  I have a VB.NET project that runs a Shell command that has been working fine for days.  However, today I started working on it again and it now give me a namespace error and the test "Shell" is underlined in red indicating a problem with the code.  I can not think of what changed (but of course something must have) nor how to fix this.  The error shown below reads

> 'System.Windows.Shell' is a namespace and cannot be used as an
> expression

The code is as follows:

```
Dim procID as Integer = Shell(my_command)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

[image: VB.NET Code with Error1]

Comment: Is this a WPF app? Or did you add PresentationFramework references later? -- Add one or more tags that describe the type of your Project.

Comment: The code above is associated with a WPF form within my project.  The form is named frmTest.xaml.vb and the code is on frmTest.xaml.vb.  Let me know if that does not answer your question.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: So, you have a WPF app (which uses Windows, not Forms, that's WinForms thing). This is the PresentationFramework's namespace [System.Windows.Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell) -- Did you port this app from Console or WinForms to WPF? Anyway, you cause `Process.Start()` to execute commands. Add the `wpf` tag to your question and a description of what .Net version you're targeting. -- Since you haven't, you should take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `Shell` in VB.NET in the first place. It's a holdover from VB6. Use `Process.Start` instead. You will then not see a name clash with a different entity named `Shell`.

For the record, if you really wanted to use that `Shell` function then you could qualify the name as `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Shell` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell` or `Interaction.Shell`. Because `Interaction` is a module, you can omit the type name when referring to the method. If it was a class then you'd have had to use `Interaction.Shell` in the first place, just as you have to use `Process.Start`, i.e. qualify the `Start` method with the `Process` class.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try Process Start as was not aware of that option.